# iPhone Development, How to Programmatically Call a NavigationController back button from another tab?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Here's the setup:

I have a tab bar controller with two tabs.  There is a navigation controller on top the second tab, so that I can view details from a table.

On tab #1, I have a button.  When this button is pressed, it switches the selected tab over to tab #2.

My problem is this:  Let's say I go to tab #2, then I select a line from my table to view the detailed information.  Then, instead of hitting the "back" button to return to the base view, I select tab#1.  Then I press my button.  Tab#2 loads, but it is still showing the detailed view, instead of the table view that I want.

I know how to programmatically press the button.
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

But how would I do that when the button pressed method is inside the class for tab#1, which knows nothing of tab#2's navigation controller?

Hope that makes sense.  Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Okay, I finally got it to work.  The solution that was suggested gave me a good jumping off point.  Here is the code that finally worked for me:

`ARFinderAppDelegate appDelegate = (ARFinderAppDelegate)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    [appDelegate.booksNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;`

I had to access the class that contained the NavigationController through an instance of my application delegate.  I also had to remove the "objectAtIndex:1" because my application would crash.

Thanks for all the help, this has been a great learning experience for this iPhone development newbie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use your delegate singleton.

```
[[delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tab2Index] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: "delegate" does not appear to be a keyword, and I get an error that its undefined.  If I try using "self.delegate" instead, I get another error: Request for member 'delegate' is something not a structure or union.  I know I must be missing something simple, I'm new to all of this.  Could you help me out please?  Thanks!

Comment: your app delegate is what i am referring to. Insert the name of your appdelegate file where "YourAppDelegate" is.. (this is the file with applicationDidFinishLaunching: in it and probably the logic for your tab bar controller.

YourAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

in front of the line given above.